# How to customize Example Value of RequestBody in Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have LoginUser.java as

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoginUser {
    
    private String fullName;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userValidCode;
    private String institutionCode;
    private String password;

}
```

and Controller as :

```
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "logginUser", dataTypeClass = LoginUser.class, examples = @io.swagger.annotations.Example(value = {
        @ExampleProperty(value = "{'userEmail': 'test','password':'test'}") }))
@PostMapping(value = "/validateCredentials")
private ResponseEntity<LoginUser> validateUserCredentials(@RequestBody LoginUser logginUser) {}
```

I need only two member variables from LoginUser for the **validateUserCredentials** method.
But in Swagger-UI Example value, entire LoginUser schema is displayed as:

```
{
  "fullName": "string",
  "institutionCode": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "userEmail": "string",
  "userValidCode": "string"
}
```

As tried approach of **@ExampleProperty** is not working, How do I customize this example value in Swagger -UI?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices : 
The first approche is to create a DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoginUserDto {
    private String userEmail;
    private String password;
}
```

And in your service

```
private ResponseEntity<?> validateUserCredentials(@RequestBody LoginUserDto logginUser) {}
```

The second approche is using

```
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
```

Else use

```
 @JsonIgnore with @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
```

So your entity will be like :

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class LoginUser {
        @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
        private String fullName;
        private String userEmail;
        @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
        private String userValidCode;
        @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
        private String institutionCode;
        private String password;
    }
```

Hope useful

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First approach solves my query but I think I will end up creating multiple DTOs in my microservices. Second approach,although it solves this question, since I have to use same `LoginUser` across multiple rest end points which uses other member variables also, `@JsonIgnore` or `@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)` will not help